# Audio recording application specific

Tags: windows-10, audio-recording

I'm looking for an audio recording software, or multiple software that can help me achieve an audio recording by specific application. I need to still have the sound at the time.

Typically, I have multiple application running at the same time, and I need to record each of them on different tracks for later editing, different file or a different track of the same audio file, as long that I can edit them one by one. Right now, I am able to record all sound into one track and Microphone into another (I also record the video, but only the sound causse me issues).

I'm on windows 10, the best clue that I have found, is that I need to setup different virtual sound card, and redirect each application that I want to record into to a sound card and record the output of each of these virtual sound card, but I did not manage to achieve that yet.

Is there a better option, or software name that I can use ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way arround my issue, for those that are looking at the same situation.
I use a software called [VB-CABLE Virtual Audio Device](https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm) that allow me to have three virtual cable from output to input and 
[Alis Recording Tool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/alis/) that can record multiple input at the same time in different file, you could use other software like audacity running three times, I could not find a way to have one instance record three tracks (two works but you loose the stereo).

So I use the following configuration:

- Application 1 sound output to "Cable Output" (I dont need to listen that one actually)
- Application 2 sound output to "Cable-A Output" and listen the "Cable-A Input"
- Application 3 sound output to "Cable-B Output" and listen the "Cable-B Input"

And with Alis Recording Tool, I record the three Cables output, then I can edit them the way I want :)

The only drawback I have seen so far is for the Windows Audio Mixer, you don't see the application, but the cable name.

Comment: Do you want us to merge your two accounts?